# Execute "setApprovalForAll" on behalf of deployed smart contract (Solidity)

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets

I have deployed a contract which implements `Ownable` and `IERC721Receiver`.

The issue I am facing is that this particular contract does not implement any function to grant approval to other contracts in regards to the tokens held in it (ERC20, ERC721). Is there a way to execute these approval functions as one would via etherscan or remix on behalf of the contract?

I am guessing chances are slim to none!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to execute anything "on behalf of" another user or contract. One can only call a contract function that knows what to do. So, the contract author has either built in the capability or it is not possible.

Consider something like (pseudo):

```
function approveERC20Spender(address token, address spender, uint amount) external onlyOwner {
  // this contract can "approve" spenders of tokens owned by this contract
  ERC20(token).safeApprove(spender, amount);
}
```

Hope it helps.